# use of ID generator from Oracle custom function

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I'm using nHibernate trying to get the primary key ID back after an insert (.SaveOrUpdate() call). Our Oracle table generate the PK ID with its own custom function, so the sequence.NextVal isn't the correct ID that's actually saved in the table. How do I define my mapping (.hbm.xml file) so that I can get the actual ID that's inserted to the table?

I currently have the following, but the sequence coming back is not the valid one:

```
<generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">seq_jobid</param>
</generator>
```

Is there any other way to get the most recently inserted pk back to the client?

thanks.

Comment: Is the identity generated by a sequence?